# Why doesn't field injection work?

Tags: java, dependency-injection

I have a Logger class

```
public class Logger {

   public void log(){
      System.out.println("Logger vagyok!");
   }
}
```

and a Cow class which injects a Logger.

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Cow {

   @Inject
   private Logger logger;

   public void speak(){
      logger.log();
   }    
}
```

But my Main class throws NullPointerException.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("START");
       Cow cow = new Cow();
       cow.speak(); //THROW NULLPOINTER EXCEPTION HERE!
       System.out.println("END");
    }
}
```

Why doesn't my field injection work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field injection does not work itself. You need framework that implements it. For example Spring is a leading injection framework that respects either its own or "standard" injection annotations.

Comment: Thanks. Why Spring jars should I put my project's build path?

Comment: @user2693979: putting jars in the classpath won't solve your issue automagically. Some things need to be learnt and take time to understand and master. Go to the Spring website, and read tutorials and documentation. You can't become a surgeon just by asking "which bistoury should I use". Same thing for programming.

Comment: @JB Nizet, +1 for comparison with surgeon... Fortunately in worse case we can always restart the computer. Surgeon sometimes cannot...